# Fiddler error when check for update

Tags: fiddler

I'm using fiddler to test API calls.
Recently when I check for update I get the error message:
[image]

Anyone know what the issue is? Re-installing fiddler doesn't solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the update server hosted by Telerik. I get a similar error with an older version (4.4).

[image]

You should contact Telerik via fiddler@telerik.com